# Is there a way to find the current row of the iteration using 'openpyxl' on Python?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm working with a xlsx file where it is divided by sections with empty rows and each section has an information displayed in a different manner i.e. different columns.
So i'm basically trying to find the section that i'm looking for ('Ação') and create a range from its next line, where are the headers, until the next empty row so I can create a DataFrame of this range.

when I try to print the index, it returns a tuple containing the values of the row, but I couldn't find a way to return its index (integer)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

data = '2019/02/07'
symbol = 'EQTL3'
ano = data[0:4]
mes = data[5:7]
dia = data[8:10]
file = "Fundo_{}{}{}.xlsx".format(ano, mes, dia)

wb = load_workbook(filename=file, read_only=False)
ws = wb["Fundo_{}{}{}".format(ano, mes, dia)]

for cell in ws['A']:
if (cell.value == 'Ação'):
    x = int(cell.coordinate[1:]) + 1
    for index in ws.iter_rows(min_row=x, max_col=ws.max_column, max_row=ws.max_row, values_only=True):
        if (index[0] == None):
            y = ws._current_row
            break
```

I expect to receive an integer value with the index of the last row different than empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use enumerate for that....
something like this:

```
for row_idx, row_of_cells in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_row=x, values_only=True), start=1):
```